# android webkit change font size?

Tags: android, android-webview

how could I change my custom webview font size ?

```
    String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
    webView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I want to control the font(text) size of that string summary at webview.

Can I control with `addJavascriptInterface  (Object  obj, String  interfaceName)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.LARGEST);
```